# Request method and threading issue?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, proxy, httpwebrequest

I'm developing an app that scrapes a website for Google+1's, Facebook shares and Tweets. I have a request method that accepts a URL and then goes off and fetches the count for each social media type.

It's logic is as follows: -

- Take URL
- Do requests through local/default IP until we get rate limited/non-500 response
- On error

  - Call `SelectNewProxy()` which iterates over a list of proxies and returns one at random to try (a nice way of avoiding request limits for your IP)
  - Remove bad proxy from list to avoid selecting it again
  - Start a timer which increments every second
- When the timer == 600 (10 minutes)

  - Create new `WebProxy` and try to the requests behind our local/default IP again
  - Reset timer

Rinse and repeat

The code is as follows:

```
public string Request(string action)
{
      HttpWebRequest req;

      OnStatusChange(new MyArgs() { Message = "Status: Requesting..." });
      string response = string.Empty;

      while (response.Equals(string.Empty) && proxy != null)
      {
             try
             {
                  req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(action);
                  req.Proxy = proxy;
                  HandleUIMessages(action, proxy);
                  response = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
              }
              catch
              {
                  //OnProxyChange(new MyArgs() { ProxyMessage = string.Format("Proxy: {0}", proxy.Address.ToString()) });
                  RemoveProxy(proxy);

                  if (!timer.Enabled)
                  {
                      timer.Interval = (int)TimeInterval.OneSecond;
                      timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
                      timer.Enabled = true;
                      timer.Start();
                  }
                  WebProxy reset = new SelectNewProxy();     
                  proxy = counter >= 600 ? reset : proxy = SelectNewProxy();
               }
      }
      return response;
}
```

It's worth mentioning that I'm using `ThreadPool` and each request is running in it's own thread. It seems like it would work but I don't get the desired effect, the counter reaches '600' and sets `proxy = reset` but it appears to only do it very briefly, possibly only for the first thread that hits it? Then `timer_Elapsed` is called and `counter` is reset. Could it be that a thread is hitting it, assigning `proxy = reset` and then because `counter` has now been reset (no longer >= 600), all subsequent queued up threads call `SelectNewProxy()`? Feel like I'm rambling but hopefully someone can make sense of what I'm trying to say and if I'm right in my guess, how can I ensure that all threads get `proxy = reset` and retry our inital IP?

Any help is much appreciated!

Thankyou

Comment: You don't detail where counter is updated; might be hard for someone to figure out why counter is no longer >= 600 without that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How have you declared `proxy`?  If you are reading/writing its value on multiple threads, you should make sure you declare it with the `volatile` keyword, otherwise writes to `proxy` on one thread may not be observed by others.

e.g.:

```
volatile WebProxy proxy;
```

Comment: Just declaring it publicly in global scope. I actually managed to get this problem sorted by waiting a little longer before resetting the counter (allows the other threads to catch up) but it's obviously a poor solution so i'll definitely give this a go thanks!

Comment: There is a wealth of practical information on `volatile` in .Net here:  http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2008/06/13/VolatileReadsAndWritesAndTimeliness.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have a scoping problem. If I interpreted your post correctly, you create a thread for each call to the Request method you posted.

Anything declared in the method obviously is part of your new thread. Anything outside the method is likely to not be part of your new thread. This means you may end up with multiple threads trying to do stuff to state that is shared between threads. In this case you access proxy from multiple threads. As this is an instance of an object you should lock it before setting the proxy variable.
Us lock (proxy) { // code using proxy } to do a thread safe set to that variable.